# How to update ArcGIS Server MapServer service without re-cache?

Tags: arcgis-server, map-service, cache

I published a cached map service with set of attributes. I need to add / remove published attributes, but I want to use old cache, because there was no change in the geometry. Is there a way how to use old cache? I tried to create new service and copy cache into its cache directory, but ArcGIS seems to recache anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just overwrite the existing service when you begin the publishing, and when you do that you are given a chance to keep the existing cache or delete it. Tell it to keep it. It's super easy.